# Database design: storing hourly analytics for thousands of seperate apps

Tags: mysql, database, schema, analytics

I'm interested in designing a database that tracks real-time usage statistics from as many as thousands of apps. Every time an app is loaded, a PHP script would be called which increments the current hours count, for the relevant app, by one. What's the fastest and cleanest way to do this in MySQL?

Aggregate data needs to be able to be compiled quickly, showing, for instance, every hours traffic for the last 24 hours, or every days traffic for the last 30 days, for an app.

If everything was stored in a single table it would mean creating new columns either for each hour, or each app, which doesn't sound right. Storing each app in its own table sounds like it would mean making design changes would be a nightmare. Is MySQL a bad choice for this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a broad question, but I think there is a narrower answer.  Create a table that has the following columns:

- Application name (or id)
- Hour specifier (this might be multiple columns and include the date)

As well as other columns, such as:

- Created datetime
- unique (auto-incremented) id for each row

Your code would then *insert* a row into this table.  You don't specifically need a count, and an `update` incurs more overhead than an `insert`.

If the resulting queries are not fast enough, then think about how to optimize this.  First think about indexes.  Then think about periodically (say once per hour) extracting data for a reporting table.

Comment: So I'd insert a new row for every single impression?

Comment: @JimSreven . . . Probably that is the fastest method.  If you have a large load on the system, then there are other alternatives, but it is usually best to start with something that works.